# Can I change my Flickr account to use Gmail instead of my Yahoo account?

Tags: flickr, yahoo-account

I want to delete my Yahoo account (do you need to ask why?) but I realised it's used to login to Flickr. Flickr allows you to [transfer your account to a different Yahoo account](https://www.flickr.com/account/transfer/) and allows you to [create an account using Gmail](http://blog.flickr.net/en/2010/10/28/sign-up-for-flickr-with-your-google-account/) but there doesn't seem to be any way to transfer a Yahoo account to a Gmail account.

Comment: FYI, [soon you will be able to change your login](https://blog.flickr.net/en/2019/03/04/flickr-login-freedom-is-here/), but not to Gmail.